# Download AD Performance Report using Adword API V201402

Tags: google-ads-api

I am able to download  APR (AD Performance Report) and CPR reports with the google adword API version 201309 but when i upgrading DLL with latest API version V201402 ,i am able to download CPR file only and getting error to download APR file (AD Performance Report).

The Columns which i am using are listed below

```
ImageAdUrl
AccountCurrencyCode
AccountDescriptiveName
AccountTimeZoneId
AdGroupAdDisapprovalReasons
AdGroupId
AdGroupName
AdGroupStatus
AdNetworkType1
AdNetworkType2
AdType
AssistClicks
AssistImpressions
AssistImpressionsOverLastClicks
AveragePosition
BounceRate
CampaignId
CampaignName
CampaignStatus
ClickAssistedConversions
ClickAssistedConversionsOverLastClickConversions
ClickAssistedConversionValue
Clicks
ConversionRate
ConversionRateManyPerClick
Conversions
ConversionsManyPerClick
ConversionValue
Cost
CostPerConversion
CostPerConversionManyPerClick
CreativeApprovalStatus
CreativeDestinationUrl
Ctr
CustomerDescriptiveName
Date
DayOfWeek
Description1
Description2
Device
DevicePreference
DisplayUrl
ExternalCustomerId
Headline
Id
ImageCreativeName
ImpressionAssistedConversions
ImpressionAssistedConversionsOverLastClickConversions
ImpressionAssistedConversionValue
Impressions
IsNegative
KeywordId
Month
MonthOfYear
PercentNewVisitors
PrimaryCompanyName
PrimaryUserLogin
PromotionLine
Quarter
SharedSetName
Status
TotalConvValue
Url
ValuePerConv
ValuePerConversion
ValuePerConversionManyPerClick
ValuePerConvManyPerClick
ViewThroughConversions
Week
Year
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Please look in this. I found that the columns have been slightly changed.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#ad-group